# What is the correct way to identify if the folder exist on ADLS gen 2 account or not

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-data-lake

I am working in scala and spark environment where I want to read parquet file. Before I read, I want to check if the file exists or not. I am writing the following code in jupyter notebook but it does not work - meaning it does not show any frame because the function testDirExist returns false

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val hadoopfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def testDirExist(path: String): Boolean = {
  val p = new Path(path)
  hadoopfs.exists(p) && hadoopfs.getFileStatus(p).isDirectory
}
val pt = "abfss://container@account.dfs.core.windows.net/blah/blah/blah

val exists = testDirExist(pt)
if(exists)
{
val dataframe = spark.read.parquet(pt)
    dataframe.show()
}
```

However, the following code works. It shows data frame

```
val k = spark.read.parquet("abfss://container@account.dfs.core.windows.net/blah/blah/blah)
k.show()
```

Can anyone help me how can I check if the file exists or not?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems that the FileSystem created with the hadoop configuration points to the local FileSystem.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration is not populated automatically. You have to set them with the values like in @Chen Meyouhas answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the default filesystem to your storage account:

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    import java.io.PrintWriter

    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "abfss://<container_name>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net")
    conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
    conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
    conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<client_id>")
    conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<secret>")
    conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token")

    val fs= FileSystem.get(conf)
    val ostream = fs.create(new Path("/abfss_test.out"))
    val pwriter = new PrintWriter(ostream)
    try {
      pwriter.write("Azure Datalake Gen2 test")
      pwriter.write("\n")
    }
    finally {
      pwriter.close()
    }
//  check if the file we've just created exists
    println(fs.exists(new Path("/abfss_test.out")))
```